# What is the fp-style way of doing "naive hashmap"

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a list of pairs of format `(a: A, x: Int)`, and `x` do not duplicate in the list. Now I know that `x` is within a certain range `0 until n`, I want to make an array of size `n`, whose `i`th element is of type `Option[A]`. If there is a pair `(a, i)` in the original list, it is `Some(a)`, otherwise it is `None`. A simple example:

```
Original List (n = 6):
(a1, 1)
(a2, 2)
(a3, 5)
Desired Output:
(0, None)
(1, Some(a1))
(2, Some(a2))
(3, None)
(4, None)
(5, Some(a3))
```

For sure we can just get a mutable array, go through the original list and fill in corresponding elements. But what is the fp-style way of doing that, **given that time complexity should not be superlinear to `n`**? Maybe it is an easy question but I just cannot get my mind around... Hope someone could help out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a large collection and many/large gaps this will waste memory. I would suggest you to use a `Map[Int,B]` instead and use the `get` operation, which returns an `Option[B]`. The swaping can be done as follows:

```
scala> List("a1"->1, "a2"->2, "a3"->5)
res3: List[(java.lang.String, Int)] = List((a1,1), (a2,2), (a3,5))

// swap the elements and create a Map
scala> res3.map(_.swap).toMap
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] = Map(1 -> a1, 2 -> a2, 5 -> a3)

scala> res3.map(_.swap).toMap.get(3)
res5: Option[java.lang.String] = None

scala> res3.map(_.swap).toMap.get(1)
res6: Option[java.lang.String] = Some(a1)
```

Comment: Yes I realized what I was asking for is almost a standard map. I can also get what I exactly want from your solution (for which there is a good reason in my problem). Just go through `0~n` and query the map! If access is constant time then we are still linear. Anyway thanks!

Comment: Index access to a `List[A]` is O(n). If you want O(1) use an `IndexedSeq[A]` instead.

Comment: I mean access to a `Map`, not a `List`. Isn't it near constant, if hashing is well done?

Comment: Normally that should be true.

Comment: I'm doing this very often for performance reasons. Of course the data should be as dense as possible. For performance reasons, I would suggest to use `null` instead of `Option`.